Maximum Lower Bound for Points Bounded by a Rectangular Cuboid
I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given two points $p_1=(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $p_2=(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ on the plane, denote by $\mathcal{R}(p_1,p_2)$ the rectangular cuboid with sides parallel to the coordinate axes and with $p_1$ and $p_2$ as opposite corners, that is, \begin{align} \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:\min\{x_1, x_2\} \le x \le \max\{x_1, x_2\},\min\{y_1, y_2\} \le y \le \max\{y_1, y_2\}, \min\{z_1,z_2\} \le z \le \max\{z_1,z_2\}\}.\end{align} Find the largest value of $k$ for which the following statement is true: for all sets $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ with $|\mathcal{S}|=2024$, there exist two points $p_1, p_2\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $|\mathcal{S}\cap\mathcal{R}(p_1, p_2)|\geq k$.

The first thing I tried was solving the same problem but for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and, instead of $\mathcal{R}(p_1,p_2)$ being a rectangular cuboid, it is a rectangle. In this simpler case, the solution I found used the extremal principle, just choose the following points: $p_{\max(x)}, p_{\min(x)}, p_{\max(y)}$ and $p_{\min(y)}$; which have the greatest $x$ coordinate, the smallest $x$ coordinate, the greatest $y$ coordinate and the smallest $y$ coordinate, respectively. Now, consider the five regions $$\mathcal{R}(p_{\min(x)},  p_{\max(y)}), \mathcal{R}(p_{\max(y)},  p_{\max(x)}), \mathcal{R}(p_{\max(x)},  p_{\min(y)}), \mathcal{R}(p_{\min(y)}, p_{\min(x)})  \text{ and } \mathcal{R}(p_{\max(x)},  p_{\min(x)}).$$
Clearly all points are found in one of those five regions, which implies, by the pigeonhole principle, that one of those regions contains at least $$\lceil \frac{2024-4}{5}\rceil=404 \text{ points}$$ We can finish up by considering a construction in which the greatest number of points bounded is $404$ (or $406$ if we add the points at the corners). Consider the following:


On each rectangular region there are $406$ points and $404$ if we don't count the corners.

After finding this solution, I tried to tackle the original problem by generalizing my approach and trying to use the extremal principle and the pigeonhole principle again; however, I can't make it work since $\mathcal{R}(p_{\max(x)},p_{\max(z)}), \mathcal{R}({p_\min(x)},{p_\max(y)})$, etc. don't have to enclose all the points. For example, if the points with maximum and minimum $x,y$ and $z$ are found along the axis, all the regions made by any two of those points are planes, so generally they won't bound the rest of the points.
If something is unclear I can give further explanations on the comments. I would hugely appreciate any help, thanks beforehand.

1/ FYI If the 405 points are in the middle gap, then you should state what the $R(p_1, p_2)$ is.  $\quad$ 2/ Can you elaborate on why extending this approach to the 6 points min/max of x/y/z doesn't work? I agree that $P(max_x, max_z)$ might become a 2-d figure, but that's also true of the 2-d case where $P(max_x, min_y)$ might be a 1-d figure).

@CalvinLin I edited the post to correct some minor mistakes and make it clearer, I hope the issue that arises on the 3D case when trying to generalize the argument is better understood now. Thanks for your help.

I can show that $k\ge 7$ as follows. Let $n=2024$, $\mathcal S=\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$, such that $p_i=(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for each natural $i\le n$, and the sequence $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is nondecreasing. Erdős–Szekeres theorem implies that there exists a set $I\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $|I|\ge 45$ and the sequence $(y_i)_{i\in I}$ is (not necessarily strictly) monotonic. Similarly, there exists a set $I'\subset I$ such that $|I'|\ge 7$ and the sequence $(z_i)_{i\in I'}$ is (not necessarily strictly) monotonic. Then the set $\{p_i:i\in I'\}$ is contained in the rectangle $\mathcal R(p_{\min I'},p_{\max I'})$.
Moreover, suppose that the sequence $(y_i)_{i\in I}$ is strictly monotonic. Consider points $q_i=(y_i,z_i)$, $i\in I$. Your results for twodimensional case suggest that there exists a set $I'\subset I$ with $|I'|\ge\left\lceil \frac{|I|+6}{5}\right\rceil\ge 11$ such that the set $\{q_i:i\in I'\}$ is contained in the rectangle $\mathcal R(q_{\min I'},q_{\max I'})$. Since the sequence $(y_i)_{i\in I}$ is strictly monotonic, for each $i\in I'$, the number $x_i$ belong to the segment with the endpoints $x_{\min I'}$ and $x_{\max I'}$. Then the set $\{p_i:i\in I'\}$ is contained in the rectangle $\mathcal R(p_{\min I'},p_{\max I'})$. The condition that the sequence $(y_i)_{i\in I}$ is strictly monotonic can be relaxed due to the possibility to approximate the points $p_i$ by the points with distinct entries.

Using the Erdös-Szekeres theorem is definitely a good idea to get a lower bound on $k$; however, I doubt it can get us to the solution. If we apply the same logic to the bidimensional case we get that $k\ge 45$ which is really far away from the actual value $k=406$. I believe that the reason for the bound produced with the Erdös-Szekeres theorem to be so far away is that we don't need $(y_i){i\in I}$ to be monotonic and it is enough to have, for some $I\subset{1,2,\ldots,n}$, $y{\min I} \le y_i \le  y_{\max I}$ for any $i\in I$; which is a less constraining condition.

@Torrente The problem is how to ensure this less constrained conditions relaxing the monotonicity. Also I tried to apply Dilworth's and Mirsky's theorems, but failed to obtain a better bound. On the other hand, I updated the answer.

The problem hasn't been fully solved but, anyways, I think that you are the one who deserves the bounty.
